# The new leaves of my ponytail palm are cracking at the base, why and how do I fix it?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, palm

You can see my ponytail palm in the first picture. I have begin to notice that the new leaves after reaching a certain length start to crack near the base, (picture 2).
In picture 3 you can see how the crack is beginning to appear in what was a normal shoot. Can someone help me understand why its happening and what should I do to fix it.

[image: picture1]
[image: picture2]
[image: picture3]

Comment: Do you have a cat or pet that could be sitting on your plant when you aren't around?

Comment: i have no pets. just me and my plants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mechanical damage, so in other words something fell onto the plant or the plant fell itself on the floor. Maybe ask your partner or other people in your household what happend here.

Comment: makes sense, thanks.